# content of website is in way of menu in mobile format

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple responsive menu in HTML AND CSS, everything seems to work so far however I have some issue with it in mobile format. Basically when the menu opens up, the text that's below it is in its way and am unable to see the menu items.

```css
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
html {
    font-family:"helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}
.nav{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
    text-align:right;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}
.menu{
    margin:0 30px 0 0;
}
.menu a{
    clear:right;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:gray;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
span{
    color:#54D17A;
}
label{
    margin:0 40px 0 0;
    font-size:26px;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: none;
    width:26px;
    float:right;
}
#toggle{
    display:none;
}

/*Media*/
@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
    label{
        display:block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .menu{
        text-align: center;
        width:100%;
        display:none;
    }
    .menu a{
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
        margin:0;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
    #toggle:checked + .menu{
        display:block;
    }
    #menu a:clicked + .menu {
        display:none;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href = "#">Business</a>
            <a href = "Services.html">Services</a>
            <a href = "#">Learn more</a>
            <a href = "#"><span>Free Trial</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stuff">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus similique voluptatum quas sit accusantium molestiae, cupiditate magnam soluta, ab inventore possimus placeat ipsum eum perspiciatis ipsam nobis nulla tenetur assumenda.
    </div>
```

As you can see when in mobile mode, and you open the menu, the text on the site is in the way and user is unable to see the menu selections.

is there a way to push down the content below the menu so that menu is visible? Or an alternative solution so that the menu is clearly visible to the user as well as the toggle icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps to fix this, assuming you want the nav to drop down in front of the content: the nav needs a background color, and it needs a higher z-index than the main content, so that the menu renders in front and the content sits behind it.

```css
.menu {
    margin:0 30px 0 0;

    /* position the menu in front of the content */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

    /* and make sure the content doesn't show through from behind */
    background-color: white;
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want all the content to *move down vertically* so it's *below* the nav, check out the other answer by Epicular.

Comment: the problem here is toggle gets hidden and now I cannot close the menu unless i click on one of the items in the menu

Answer (score 0):

**Use javascript to toggle the menu**

```css
  html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
  text-align: right;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu a {
  clear: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

span {
  color: #54D17A;
}

label {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  float: right;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}


/*Media*/

@media only screen and (max-width:500px) {
  .stuff {
  position:relative;
    z-index: 9;
  }
  label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menu {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaeb;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  #toggle:checked+.menu {
    display: block;
  }
  #menu a:clicked+.menu {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Business</a>
    <a href="Services.html">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    <a href="#"><span>Free Trial</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="stuff">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus similique voluptatum quas sit accusantium molestiae, cupiditate magnam soluta, ab inventore possimus placeat ipsum eum perspiciatis ipsam nobis nulla tenetur assumenda.
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what you did since you didn't explain your changes, but the text now disappears completely.

Comment: You're problem solved right. I set the `z-index` to the items to be shown and set a background to the parent. Seriously a downvote?

Comment: Text disappears because the menu items are in the top now. Now what you have to do is initially hide the menu items in css `display:none`. Then write javascript to toggle the menu items for icon or menu label click

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `nav` class is a fixed height of 50px. If you kill that in your media query, the menu will take up its own space and push the text down.

Comment: if I set height to 0px in media, then the text is all the way up at the top of the screen, you can still see the toggle and yes it pushes the text down when you click on it. If I set the margin-top to 50px then it looks better, however, if I open the menu, there's a 50px gap in between the menu and the text

Comment: All should be fine if you just set `height` to `auto` in your media query for the class `nav`. You don't need any extra margins (unless you're styling it).

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .nav{
        position: relative;
    }

    #toggle:checked + .menu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 51px;
        z-index: 100;
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: absolute sets it's position with parent with relative property. Elements with absolute positioning is removed from the flow of elements on the page. element with this type of positioning is not affected by other elements and it doesn't affect other elements. 
 
i have applied relative property to nav class & menu is absolute, so it will place itself according to nav (it's relative parent). Also it is placing itself at 51px from top i.e it's relative parent.